# Image scaling for tablets

Tags: android, image, imageview, tablet

I have an image I want to display in ImageView in my layout. As I don't want a distorted Image, I use `android:scaleType = "center"`.

It looks good on medium and small devices, on large devices (7" and 10"), it is to small and you can see the borders. How can I prevent this?

Comment: use bigger images for bigger screens

Comment: Is there a way to use the same image for different screensizes without distorting it by using "fitxy"?

Comment: No and fitXY disregards the original aspect ratio so it will be more distorted

Comment: found a way. "centerCrop"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this property:

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

Comment: Yep, figured it already out by myself, but still thank you! I will mark this as the accepted answer for people looking at this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use Big  Size Images And use android:scaleType="FitXY"

Comment: That distorts the image because I use it as a background -> diferent resolutions